# Is there a way of using an interface type discriminator as a string union?

Tags: typescript

So for the following simplified example with a union of two interfaces with a "type" discriminator:

```
type ABBA = A | B;
interface A { type: 'a', argForA: string }
interface B { type: 'b', argForB: boolean }
```

I would like to be able to construct an object but limit its keys to the type discriminators - so

```
const config = {
  a: 123,
  b: 234,
  c: 345, // should error as c is not a type discriminator of ABBA
}
```

What i'm after is essentially the opposite of the `Record<A,B>` utility type, but i can't see anything in the [utility type documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) that functions this way.

I have tried searching online for an answer, but the answers are clouded by an overwhelming number of tutorials on how to use unions on interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```js
type ABBA = A | B;

interface A { type: 'a', argForA: string }
interface B { type: 'b', argForB: boolean }

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type OnlyDiscriminators = Values<ABBA>

const config: Record<OnlyDiscriminators, number> = {
    a: 123,
    b: 234,
    c: 345, // error
}
```

[enter link description here](https://tsplay.dev/NDDglN)

`Values` - obtains a union of common/shared props of `A` and `B`. Since discriminator should be shared property, Values returns `a` | `b`

`Record<OnlyDiscriminators, number>` creates a hash map data structures where `OnlyDiscriminators` represents keys and `number` represents values.

However, your `A` and `B` interfaces might have more props in common.

Consider this example:

```js
type ABBA = A | B;

interface A { type: 'a', argForA: string, id: string }
interface B { type: 'b', argForB: boolean, id: string }

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
type GetDiscriminators<D extends string, Obj extends Record<D, unknown>> = Values<Pick<Obj, D>>

type OnlyDiscriminators = GetDiscriminators<'type', ABBA>

const config: Record<OnlyDiscriminators, number> = {
    a: 123,
    b: 234,
    c: 345, // error
}
```

Comment: ah yes - this is exactly it! I knew there would be an elegant simple solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
interface A {
  type: 'a',
  a: number;
}

interface B {
  type: 'b',
  b: string;
}

type AORB = A | B;

const x: AORB = {
  type: 'b',
  b: 's'
}

const y: AORB = {
  type: 'a',
  a: 2
}

// Will not compile
const z: AORB = {
  type :'b',
  a: 2
}

// Will not compile
const n: AORB = {
  type :'a',
  b: "2"
}
```

This looks very similar to your own suggestion, and it works just fine.